# Reading data from char* and converting to char[]

Tags: c++, char

I feel weird to ask about it because problem seems trivial. Sorry, but somehow I can't make it work after checking various StackOverflow questions.

Idea is:

1. I have a *.txt config file in which user can change some parameters. One of them is "FILE_PATH" where user has to write the location to which files would be saved.
2. Because of that I don't know how many characters will be written to filepath.
3. I managed to save the characters in char* variable and it works (printf displays right directory in %s)

   ```
   if (!strcmp(tmp_str, "FILE_PATH")) {
       audioFileConfig.filePath = token;
       printf("RECORDING_FILEPATH = %s\n", audioFileConfig.filePath);
   }
   ```
4. I try to access the audioFileConfig.filePath from code and create whole file name from it:

   ```
   // getting time stamp
   char* recStartTimeStamp = createTimeStamp();

   //creating file name
   char fileName[20];
   sprintf(fileName, ".audio_%d_%d.wav", (channelId +1), part);

   //reading filePath from config
   char path[256];
   strncpy(path, audioFileConfig.filePath, 256);

   //merging chars
   char* streamFileName;
   streamFileName = new char[strlen(path) + strlen(recStartTimeStamp) + strlen(fileName) + 1];
   strcpy(streamFileName, path);
   strcat(streamFileName, recStartTimeStamp);
   strcat(streamFileName, fileName);

   //check what's inside
   cout<< "\nCreated file: " << streamFileName;
   ```

But what I get at start of the filename are just random ASCI characters. What is a right way of connecting it with whole string? Field filepath is `char*`.

Comment: Have you considered using snprintf?  It would be cleaner than the copy and cats and would also give you the number of items protection.  Also, it's weird to suddenly throw a "new char..." in the middle there.  I'm always uncomfortable instantiating chars >:^).  I'd recommend changing that to a streamFileName = malloc(...) and free it when you're through.

Comment: Have you printed `audioFileConfig.filepath` in the code before you do the `strncpy()`?  You may have assigned a local variable to the `filepath` element and that has been screwed up by the time you use it outside the function where you read it.  Since this is C++, you should probably be using a `std::string`; failing that, consider using (or implementing and using) `strdup()` to copy the value for the configuration structure/class.

Comment: Use `asprintf` if your library has it...

Comment: In C++ use `std::string`.

Comment: I've changed filepath type from char* to std::string and used audioFileConfig.filePath.c_str(). Now it works. Thanks.